# Discussion : Low quality answers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have seen a lot of post (Well, it's 3 only) being flagged particularly of following user ;

@alexey boltynov (https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/71919/alexey-boltynov)

The answer he gives may or may not be correct but he gives a very vague explanation of it.

What should we do in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should we do in these cases ?

Short answers do not have to be wrong. It's difficult in some cases as long as the user tries to answer - and isn't completely wrong - it doesn't even deserve a down vote.

If you want to "educate" people, maybe leave a short comment and ask for some explanation?